# How to reactivate a question?

Tags: support

I asked a [question](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/51870/27101). It was put on hold, then I edited it, now how do I activate it again?

Is it a good idea to re-post the question by deleting the previous one? Because, the process of reviewing a question currently "on hold", takes a lot of time and possibly gets precipitated.

Also if I post it anew, then I'm probable to get constructive responses on how to improve my question.

If there's any problem in my question, please inform me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you edit a question after it is closed, it goes into a que where users vote on whether to reopen it or not:

[image]

It gets reopened after receiving a certain number of votes. Your question has not currently received the required number of reopen votes.

This could be either because:

- The reason the question was closed has still not been resolved OR
- The users who vote are not active on the site or this has not come under their attention.

Comment: Then how would I know how to improve my question to render it eligible for S.E. There's no scope of recieving constructive responses

Comment: @AbuSafwanMdfarhan there are enough help pages and usually constructive comments showing what is wrong with your post.